# width() returning `null` on a DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, layout, width

I have the following object

```
<div class='app_advert'><a href="/apps">GET THE APPS</a></div>
```

whicch I'll refer to as `x` I am trying to position automatically above a another element (`y`), I want to line up the middle of the objects, so my theory goes thus:

```
x_width = $(x).width();
y_width = $(y).width();
y_position = $(y).offset().left;

x_horizontal_position =  y_position+(y_width/2)-(x_width/2)
```

I am trying to fetch the width of `x` using:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    object_width = jQuery('.apps_advert').width();
    console.log(object_width);
});
```

but it is returning `null`.

I am also applying the following CSS, in case this may affect things:

```
    div.app_advert{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;

    font-size: 17pt;
    top: 0;

}
div.app_advert a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Your checking apps_advert against app_advert. Also checking against a class won't return a single element. Need to set id=app_advert and check #app_advert.

Comment: What does `console.log(jQuery('.apps_advert').length)` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is `app_advert` but you jQuery code tries to find `apps_advert` (*notice the plural of `app` to `apps`*)

so try with

```
object_width = jQuery('.app_advert').width();
```

Answer (score 1):

If its `display: none` it has no width. (If `null` or `0` is the correct value I don't know.)

**EDIT**: As the others noticed you have a typo in the code "apps" vs "app" in which case null is expected. But still if the element is hidded using display: none, the width should be 0.

Comment: didn't do the downvote, but just to clarify, the width isn't null

Comment: No, I expected it to be 0 (the integer zero), but I'm not too familiar with jquery (which could have redefined it for some reason) and I would not at all be surprised if IE returned null or -9025394 or similar for a display:none element.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
object_width = jQuery('.apps_advert').width();
```

to this

```
object_width = jQuery('.app_advert').width();
```

your div has `app_advert` class but in your code you have writen `apps_advert`, and this class doesn't exist.
This is the reason why you are getting **null**